# Retrieve object from jquery in php script

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm trying to rebuild an object encoded with Json but i'm not getting any value.

JQuery:

```
$.post("views/insert_tasks.php",{ clickedRows : clickrows , <?php echo "tasks:'" . json_encode($tasks) . "'"; ?> }, function(data)
{

});
```

this is the PHPcode to retrieve the object:

```
$tasks = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['tasks']), true);
```

$tasks is empty after execute the code above.

This is what I'm getting with the $_POST['tasks']:

```
[{"task_id":"1","description":"<p>Fazer heroi</p>","createdat":"Saturday 22nd of May 2010 11:37:37 PM","createdby":"Miguel Cardoso","max_requests":"2","max_duration":"5","job_id":"Concept Artist"},{"task_id":"2","description":"<p>teste2</p>","createdat":"Sunday 23rd of May 2010 11:23:55 AM","createdby":"Miguel Cardoso","max_requests":"2","max_duration":"5","job_id":"3D Modeller"},{"task_id":"3","description":"<p>teste3</p>","createdat":"Sunday 23rd of May 2010 11:45:39 AM","createdby":"Miguel Cardoso","max_requests":"1","max_duration":"10","job_id":"Writer"}]
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think you are... given the JSON and the code, it should work.

Can you share some more info as to how you determine that $tasks is empty, and verify the content of $_POST['tasks']?

For $tasks at least you should try to var_dump it...

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? The above code worked for me as well.

Comment: You don't need to call stripslashes - just json_decode($_POST['tasks'], true);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your reply Brian.
I get it work replacing:

```
$tasks = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['tasks']), true);
```

by

```
$tasks = json_decode($_POST['tasks']);
```

I was seeing the content of the variable $tasks writing it to a file.
Here is the all code of php file:

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once("../database/db_connect.php");

if(isset($_POST['clickedRows'])) 
{ 
    $clickedRows = json_decode($_POST['clickedRows']);
    $tasks = json_decode($_POST['tasks']); 

    foreach($clickedRows as $i)
    {
        $task_id = $tasks[$i]->task_id;

        $myFile = "debug.txt";
        $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
        fwrite($fh, $_POST['tasks']);

        fclose($fh);

        $user_id = $_SESSION['id'];
        $requestedat = date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');
        $requestedby = $_SESSION['first'] . " " . $_SESSION['last'];


        $sql ="INSERT INTO 
        darkfuture.users_tasks
        (
          `task_id`,
          `user_id`,
          `requestedat`,
          `requestedby`
        ) 
        VALUE (
          $task_id,
          $user_id,
          '$requestedat',
          '$requestedby'
        )";

        $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
   }
}
?>
```

Comment: Side note, the 2nd arg for true makes the entire json object an associative array instead of an array of objects (pointing it out since the OP had it in there and you don't)